# Как узнать в какой папке работает Gulp (чтобы создать в этой папке подпапку)?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp4, webp

Я хочу автоматизировать конвертацию картинок в webp формат. Чтобы не делать это вручную или через онлайн-конвертеры, я решил использовать gulp 4 и gulp-webp.

Вот такая структура вложенности папок в моём проекте:

[image]

Я хочу, чтобы Gulp, когда он находит картинку, чтобы он на этом же уровне вложенности создавал папку с названием "webp" и сконвертированную картинку закидывал в эту папку.

Нужен вот такой результат:

[image: в]

Мой Gulpfile.js:

```js
let gulp = require('gulp'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp');

gulp.task('webp', () => {
    // './dev/img/**/*.{png,gif,jpg}' - все файлы в img и все файлы в подпапках в img


        return gulp.src('./dev/img/**/*.{png,gif,jpg}')
            .pipe(webp())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(gulp.src)) //что-то типа такого, но это не работает

            //я хочу, чтобы когда картинка конвертируется в webp, чтоб скрипт закидывал её в попадпку с названием webp
            //например, если картинка находится в img/image.png, то конвертироваться должна в img/webp/image.webp
            //если в img/header/image.png, то в img/header/webp/header.webp
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, так сделать не получиться, если только не написать отдельный плагин для gulp. Но можно сохранять в отдельную папку с той же структурой.

```js
const { task, src, dest } = require('gulp');
const webp = require('gulp-webp');

task('webp', () => {
return src('./dev/img/**/*.{png,gif,jpg}')
  .pipe(webp())
  .pipe(dest('./dev/webp/'));
}
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]